# How does Batman know to rescue Selina Kyle outside the home of John Daggett?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-dark-knight-rises

In *The Dark Knight Rises*, Selina Kyle enters the home of John Daggett to confront his henchman for a copy of software she had been promised that would erase her name and criminal record from every database in the world. They deny that the code exists and fight her off. She faces a growing crowd of armed opponents when Batman arrives to help.

How did Batman know she was there? He had placed a tracking device on a necklace she stole near the beginning of the movie, but he had already retrieved the necklace before this scene. Was it coincidence that he arrived at that moment, and if so, why was he visiting Daggett's house himself?

Comment: _Coincidence_ my friend is underrated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

He didn't know Selina was there at all and didn't come for her, but for Dagget (and ultimately Bane). So it was indeed a coincidence that he arrived just in time.

As to the question of why he was visiting Dagget's house then, this is explained in an earlier scene. When Bruce (or rather Alfred) does some investigations about Bane, he learns that he previously worked as a mercenary for one of Dagget's rather dubious projects abroad and that Dagget most probably brought him into Gotham.

> **Bruce:** Did you check that name, Bane?
>   **Alfred:** He's a mercenary. No other known no names. Him and his men were behind a coup in West Africa that secured mining operations for our friend John Daggett.
>   **Bruce:** And Daggett has brought him here?
>   **Alfred:** So it seems.

So he concludes that Bane is likely doing some work for him and when he lost track of Bane and his men after the stock exchange robbery, Dagget was the first point to look for them and get some answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think he was chasing Selina Kyle all the time  to know what she had done with his fingerprints and did not know about what was Daggett up to. The only theory I can think of is the car that she stole from Bruce. Maybe it had a tracking device (which should be) that helped him to find her. I can't think of any other option.

Daggett's motivation was not clear to him and she said to him "..But Daggett seemed pretty interested in that mess at the stock market"

Answer (score 0):

He knew that Bane had previously worked for Dagget. He also lost track of Bane, so Bane could have been there. My second thought is he that knew that Selina Kyle was there because of the reason that she put Batman in a cage, which was that Bane had promised to erase her criminal record. He might also have put a tracking device on Selina Kyle's car.