# How did Bruce Wayne get into Gotham when Bane had blown up all the bridges?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-dark-knight-rises

After Bruce escaped from the prison, how did he manage to get into Gotham?
He had no access to his Batman-utilities.

Comment: He's Batman. That's all the explanation that is ever needed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> He had no access to his Batman-utilities.

You don't actually know that. I, for one, believe he had some.

Remember in "The Dark Knight", when he's in a restaurant, talking to Harvey, Rachel, and Natascha (a prima ballerina for the Moscow Ballet)?

> Natascha: How could you want to raise children in a city like this?
>
> Bruce: Well, I was raised here. I turned out okay.
>
> Harvey: Is Wayne Manor in the city limits?
>
> Bruce: Is... Heh... heh... The Palisades? Sure. You know, as our new DA, you might wanna figure out where your jurisdiction ends.

This means that the Wayne Manor is outside of the city. Now, he obviously couldn't come in as the Batman, since he needed to pull up a little performance to get to heavily guarded Lucius Fox, but not using the suit does not mean he couldn't use his gadgets.

How **exactly** did he get in, I'm afraid will have to remain unanswered. The Tumbler would probably be a bit to much. The Batpod is more realistic option, but still hard to sneak by. We could assume that he has a secret tunnel, but I think that too is a bit too much of a stretch, given that no hint of such a tunnel was ever given, and there were few situations when it might come in handy.

Personally, I'd go by "sneaking on foot". After all, he **is** a ninja, and has mastered their art of invisibility. He might have used the same grappling hook as he did in Hong Kong in "The Dark Knight", or he could've just climb under the one bridge that was not collapsed.

I also think that not too much though should be spent on this. Ultimately, he is Bruce Wayne, and these seemingly impossible things come easily to him. For example, finding Selina Kyle and saving her from Bane and his thugs on the roof of Daggett's mansion, or finding Rachel at just the right moment in the "Batman Begins" (the subway scene),... Plenty of perfect timings with very thin explanations (or none at all). Not to mention fixing his broken back.

After all, these movies *are* comic adaptations, and as such they do keep a healthy dose of non-realism and cartoon physics. This way they remain lighthearted fun, not burdening us with the technical details for the sake of unnecessary realism.

Comment: Good answer. But as a side note, *"finding Selina Kyle and saving her from Bane and his thugs on the roof of Daggett's mansion"* - As explained [here](http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/9493/49) he wasn't looking for *Selina* in particular anyway. *"finding Rachel at just the right moment in the "Batman Begins" (the subway scene)"* - He just tracked her from her work and needed a moment when she was alone (not knowing that other people waited for that moment, too).

Comment: @ChristianRau Of course, but it's still an awful lot of perfect timings or important coincidences. It's all *possible*, but not really *realistic*. Thank you for your addition.

Comment: Point of information: That conversation clearly indicates Wayne Manor is *near* the city limits but not outside of them. "Sure" is an affirmative answer.

Comment: @mootinator Of course, but the city spans outside of the bridged area, and since the question was even issued (and from the looks of the manor), I conclude that it is outside of the island part of the city.

Comment: Bravo! An extraordinary answer to a rather ordinary question.

Comment: Gotham is supposedly based on New York City, and despite looking like Chicago in *batman Begins* it's definitely NYC in *The Dark Knight Rises*. The pallisades is a real area in Rockland County New York on the west banks of the Hudson river outside of New York City. The entire idea of a mansion and caves fit this area.

Answer (score 0):

In Batman Begins; Bruce traveled the world for 7 years with limited resources. And he trained with Ras al Ghual on the frozen river, so he would've crossed the frozen lake near Gotham at night.